# Connection reset by peer (rabbitmq)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

```
client side py

import pika, sys, os,ssl

def main():

    context =ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.load_verify_locations("/home/dev/Desktop/files_from_ssh/ca_certificate.pem")

    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='xxx', password='xxxx')
    conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host="***",port=5672,heartbeat=60,ssl_options=pika.SSLOptions(context),
                                            virtual_host="test_environment",credentials=credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='ssl_test')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

    channel.basic_consume(queue='ssl_test', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

    channel.start_consuming()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted")
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            pass
```

on the server side tls is enabled

```
Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp/ssl, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 over TLS
Interface: [::], port: 15672, protocol: http, purpose: HTTP API
```

```
rabbitmq.conf

listeners.ssl.default               = 5672
ssl_options.cacertfile              = /home/dev/testca/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile                = /home/dev/server/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile                 = /home/dev/server/private_key.pem
ssl_options.verify                  = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert    = true
listeners.tcp = none
```

refered from this site:https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls_server_authentication.html
unable to connect to the server would someone help me out kinda new to rabbitmq
this is the error im getting
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Comment: Ever figured this issue out?

Comment: Did without ssl. It was heartbeat issue.